# Writing an Excel file in Powershell and using an equal sign in a formula

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm writing an Excel file with Powershell and I am having an issue with writing an equal sign in a formula. So for example, I have written two cells in A1 and B1

```
$Excel.cells.item(1,1) = 5 
$Excel.cells.item(1,2) = 1000
```

Now if I put a IF statement in C1, it works with everything other than an '='

```
#Works
$Excel.cells.item($i,3).Formula = '=IF(A1>3,B1*1,B1*0)'

#Doesn't work
$Excel.cells.item($i,3).Formula = '=IF(A1=5,B1*1,B1*0)'
```

I've tried everything I can think of to escape that = but still get the following error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:1 char:1
+ $Excel.cells.item($i,3).Formula = '=IF(A1=5),B1*1,B1*0)'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Any help with that would be greatly appreciated!! I know it's going to be something stupid but still...

Comment: What is `$i`? Something like `$sheet.Cells.Item(1,3).formula = '=IF(A1=3,B1*1,B1*0)'` works for me. Did you  forget `$i = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to agree with BigBen's comment that the value of `$i` is suspect.

This works for me (I couldn't paste this in a comment without losing the formatting):

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xlsx")
$objExcel.cells.item(1,1) = 5 
$objExcel.cells.item(1,2) = 1000
$objExcel.cells.item(1,3).Formula = '=IF(A1=5,B1*1,B1*0)'
$WorkBook.Close($true)
$objExcel.Quit()
```